# Weird graphical glitches (appears only on integrated display) on any Ubuntu based distro (maybe on every distro, haven't tested yet) - Lenovo Y700

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

So yeah I am running in Issue, my laptop is basically usseles so wanted to use it as my Linux introduction, prepared installation pendrive with Rufus and tried to install Kubuntu, everything was fine in setup, even while testing system without installing everything was ok, but after I installed OS and restarted PC (part of installation process) weird things started happening, like screen started vibrating (I think that I can call that vibrating/shaking, my English is just bad so I don't know how to call it) **Tried to install and reinstall display drivers multiple times on multiple installations, tried to install iGPU drivers, disable discrete GPU, launch without secure boot and Uefi (legacy mode), installed GPU drivers through software-properties-gtk,tried sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade and nothing, reinstalled Kubuntu 3 times and tried Ubuntu once, same problem, don't know how to fix it**, need help, I'll post video, sorry for bad shot and shakey hands but I think you can see whats happening, especially when system is already booted.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BAAWg9vYT0

UPDATE: MANJARO GNOME IS WORKING BUT DON'T WANT TO USE ANY ARCH BASED DISTRO.

EDIT: FORGET ABOUT IT, EVERYTHING WORKS ON EXTERNAL MONITOR, PROBLEMS ARE AS TITLE SAYS ONLY ON INTEGRATED ONE.

EDIT 2: CANT WORD MYSELF IF YOU DON'T SEE MY PROBLEM JUST OPEN VIDEO AND TAKE A LOOK ON THE EDGES FROM 0:36 TO END OF VIDEO, ITS NOT MY PHONES FAULT, ITS HOW IT LOOK.

EDIT 3: I WROTE LAPTOPS NAME, LAPTOP THAT GOT ONLY ONE GPU VERSION BUT I GUESS NEED TO PROVIDE THAT INFORMATION COZ OLD INTERNET USERS DON'T KNOW HOW TO USE GOOGLE, GTX 960M 4GB

EDIT 4: APPEARS ON BOTH KUBUNTU 21.04 AND UBUNTU 21.04 Arch based Manjaro doesn't seem to have any problems.

Comment: This looks to me like a hardware problem, especially if it's showing up on multiple operating systems that have been cleanly installed

Comment: Whats weirdest theres no problem on Windows and before launching system e.g. first Lenovo startup screen and bios, also installation and try Linux option is just fine, after system is oficially installed problem appears after first Lenovo logo.

Comment: You've provided no release details...  nor if you used a LTS release which ISO you chose to use which controls which hardware stack is installed by default (ie. HWE or GA).   I've experienced some glitches with some hardware where the solution was just switching from HWE to GA stack (ie. switch kernel, stack including kernel modules (kernel modules = *drivers*) but you've provided no details on what you tried, what was in your video, or what you're using.  Release details provide much of that detail (though LTS the media used to install dictates default stack chosen)

Comment: FYI: Kubuntu is **not** Ubuntu based; but a Ubuntu *flavor* using the same base system with just different desktop.

Comment: @guiverc I am using newest stable release of non LTS version, in Video I was using Kubuntu but exact same problem appears on Ubuntu, what most interesting Arch based distro Manjaro works just fine, but I don't want to use Arch based distro straight away after starting my journey with Linux, and what do you mean, I said what I tried.

Comment: Please be specific ; words like *latest* and *newest* are just warning flags in support as end-users have various interpretations even if we skip the *dailies* that are available...  If you're using KDE Neon - it's not a Ubuntu *flavor* and thus off-topic here (it uses a mix of LTS & non-LTS; a combination not used in Ubuntu)

Comment: @guiverc OK, I understand that I am seeking help not you, but what you on about? I said that newest stable release of non LTS Version, https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop Guess which one of these two is newest stable release, is there any newest different stable release of Ubuntu? I don't think so also why you keep talking about KDE Neon, I said what I tried and I said that same think occurs on Ubuntu so I don't think 'this is off topic here'.

Comment: Edit your post and retain essential information only. Make it concise: I don't see what graphical card you have, and I don't understand what graphical glitches you experience.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is confirmed on:

- Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1936708
- Kernel mailing list: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2021-August/123041.html
- intel drm: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/3714

Patch is deployed on kernel 5.13 as you can see in the mailing list. Until then kernel 5.11.0-22 and lower was uneffected when I tested it (didn't tested every one of them but 5.8.0-48 was stable and didn't have any issues).

I suggest downgrading your kernel to 5.8.0-48 and wait until 5.13 is released, it's already deployed on Fedora 34 and Arch based distros.

If you need help regarding to downgrading your kernel, feel free to reply.

Have a nice day!